# Any module that can be used to connect Pandas with kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I want to display the data that is contained inside my 'data.cls' file into kivy. I have used this code

```
class Show(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Show,self).__init__(**kwargs)

        with self.canvas:
            Color(.62,.91,.968,1, mode='rgba')
            Rectangle(pos=(0, 0), size=(2000, 2000))
            Color(.83,1,1,1,mode='rgba')
            Rectangle(pos=(0,140),size=(2000,1000))


        df = str((pd.read_csv('data.csv')))
        self.add_widget(Label(text=df, color=(0, 0, 0, 1)))
```

However, the result is kinda messy:
[image: Result]
Is there any way to 'tidy up' the result? Should I use any module to get better result?
Thankss

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any such module, but you can build your own display using `GridLayout`. Here is a sample code that I have used (with some small modifications for your situation):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
import pandas as pd


class CellLabel(Label):
    pass


class Show(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Show,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.fill)

    def fill(self, dt):
        # fill the GridLayout with CellLabels
        df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
        grid = self.ids.grid
        grid.cols = df.shape[1]
        for row in df.values:
            for col in row:
                txt = str(col).strip()
                if txt == 'nan':
                    txt = ''
                grid.add_widget(CellLabel(text=txt))
        Clock.schedule_once(self.do_centering)

    def do_centering(self, dt):
        # center the text in each CellLabel

        # start by getting the max width of each column
        grid = self.ids.grid
        reversed = grid.children[:]
        reversed.reverse()
        max_col_widths = [0] * grid.cols
        col = 0
        for cell in reversed:
            if cell.width > max_col_widths[col]:
                max_col_widths[col] = cell.width
            col += 1
            col = col % grid.cols

        # use those max widths to center the text in each CellLabel
        col = 0
        for cell in reversed:
            cell.width = max_col_widths[col]
            cell.halign = 'center'
            cell.text_size = cell.size
            col += 1
            col = col % grid.cols


kv = '''
<CellLabel>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: self.texture_size
    color: 0,0,0,1
<Show>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.62, 0.91, 0.968, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    ScrollView:
        GridLayout:
            id: grid
            padding: 5
            spacing: 5
            size_hint: None, None
            size: self.minimum_size
'''
class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv)
        return Show()

TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Looks much tidier now. Thanks!